# How to handle users that re-add their deleted tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Kiamlaluno edited a question to remove [selectquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selectquery) which isn't (and don't think will be) a popular tag on this site; just after this, the user [retagged the question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/8548/revisions) just for the hope to gain the "taxonomist" badge.

How should we handle these behaviors? Should we care, and declare a war ala Wikipedia regarding tags or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the tag because I think there is no need to use a tag for questions about "SELECT" queries; doing so, I was implicitly saying to the OP not to use that tag.

Keep in mind that tags used by one or two questions (I don't remember exactly) are automatically removed after X days; removing a tag that is useless is normally done to avoid somebody else picks up it, and other users start using it. If that fails, you can always propose the used tag as synonym of an existing one; if you cannot propose synonym for the already used tag, because you don't have a score of 5 on that tag, you can always propose the synonym tag here on meta. Synonym tags should be proposed when more than a user, or more than a question, is using the wrong, or not necessary tag.

Answer (score 1):

I removed it, and left a note in the revisions. I'll do a pass on single-use tags, hopefully this won't continue.

Comment: just as a reminder, tags with only one question in them over an entire six month period are automatically removed.